# How to align <th> to the center of all table elements combined?

Tags: html

I have a table. This table has 3 pictures in the front row. I also have a table header with a title for the table. But, if I use `<th align="middle">` it aligns the header only relative to the first picture (on the table) in the table. I want it to align itself relative to all the pictures, so the text would be on top of the 2nd picture.

Please help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for

```
<th align="middle" colspan="3">
```